# How can I fill array with string in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, fill

I need to fill an array with a string that is input by a user. For example user enters such string like these: "St/80" We know the length before user enters it btw.
I wanna do this:

```
    array[0]='S';
    array[1]='t';
    array[2]='/';
    array[3]=8;
    array[4]=0;
```

Comment: There is a magic command called `scanf();`. Look into it. :)

Comment: @Haris `scanf()` is rarely the correct answer to inputting a string in C. `fgets()` or `getline()` would be better choices.

Comment: @KurtStutsman, True. But for a beginner, and for the input he provided. I thought `scanf()` would be the most apt. But ya, `fgets()` is a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Look at the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char arr[10];
    scanf("%9s", arr);
    printf("%s",arr);
    return 0;
}
```

here if your input string is "St/80" then it will assign as below:

```
array[0]='S';
array[1]='t';
array[2]='/';
array[3]=8;
array[4]=0;
```

also you can increase the size of string by increasing the index of arr.

Comment: Using `scanf()` like this is a buffer exploit waiting to happen.

Comment: thats right @KurtStutsman, but here it can be a solution of this problem.

Comment: If you're going to use `scanf()` at least show them to use the `%9s` form so we're teaching beginners to code safely from the beginning. Otherwise they tend to develop long-lived poor coding practices.

Comment: thank you so much it works but I don't get "%9s" part. What "%9s" stands for? why don't we use %s instead of %9s i mean.

Comment: ok. %9s means it will take a string input which contains less than or equal to 9 characters. you can change this number.